# How do I interpret the results of the PMP exam to do better next time?

Tags: pmp, testing

After taking the PMP test, upon failure, you get a report with scores of below proficient, moderately proficient, and proficient results:

Initiating the Project

Planning the Project

Executing the Project

Monitoring and Controlling the Project

Closing the Project

How can that report guide passing on a second attempt since most training materials are divided up in alternative topics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PMBOK Guide 5th Edition clearly lists the specific knowledge areas for each of the process groups you've mentioned above. See page 60, Table 3-1. The results are telling you with knowledge areas you need to work on.